# Passing arguments by referencing parameters stored in a struct object

Tags: c#, input, methods, struct, output

I'm new to programming and C#; I don't quite understand how to pass arguments with structs and could use some help in getting this code to work..

I'm making a program to test working with structs & methods.

I'm trying to make two methods..

My displayStudent() method is supposed to take the Student type parameters from the newStudent object/instance created by the CreateStudent_Click.

CreateStudent_Click() Method grabs the user input from three TextBoxes(nameOfStudent, studentID, studentsMajor) and concatenates them to be one string(Output) which is displayed on a fourth outputTextBox after the mouse click on Create Student button.

Myy CreateStudent_Click(), is supposed to get the user input and put it into a new object/instance of Student type as well as pass an argument to DisplayStudent(newStudent) as well as call it.

Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Student_Structure
{
     struct Student
     {
         public string name;
         public string studentID;
         public string major;
     }
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
          public Form1()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
          }
     }
     private void displayStudent(ref Student student)
     {
        try
        {
            student.name = nameTextBox.Text;
            student.studentID = studentIDTextBox.Text;
            student.major = majorTextBox.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }

     private void CreateStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Declare a string to hold a line of output.
        string output;

        // Create an instance of student.
        Student newStudent = new Student();
        newStudent.name = nameTextBox.Text;
        newStudent.studentID = studentIDTextBox.Text;
        newStudent.major = majorTextBox.Text;
        // Clear the TextBoxes
        nameTextBox.Clear();
        studentIDTextBox.Clear();
        majorTextBox.Clear();
        displayStudent(Student.newStudent());
        // Clear the TextBox's current contents.
        foreach (Student student in newStudent)
        {

        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly (and this is just a rule of thumb) `struct`s should be [Immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Now there is 1000's of blogs on the internet that debate this and why and its best to read up on this.

However, by default they are mutable. Yet on saying that, there are a lot of mutable structs used in the framework like `Point`, `Size`, `Rectangle`. These `struct`s are fully mutable. This is done (against the guidelines) for the sake of performance, as it avoids the need to create new values for modification operations.

...All that aside, if you are passing a mutable `struct` in a parameter (unlike a reference type) what you get is a copy. Nothing you do will make any difference unless you pass by `ref`.

**Given a *Mutable* struct**

```
public struct Student
{
   public Student(string name, int studentId, string major)
   {
      Name = name;
      StudentId = studentId;
      Major = major;
   }

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public string Major { get; set; }

   public override string ToString() => Name + ", " + StudentId + ", " + Major;
}
```

You can simply pass by reference

```
private void MutateStudent(ref Student student)
{
   student.Name = "asd";
   student.StudentId = 234;
   student.Major = "ertyt";
}
```

or

```
private Student AbetterMutateStudent(Student student)
{
   // this is actually a copy
   student.Name = "asd";
   student.StudentId = 234;
   student.Major = "ertyt";
   return student;
}
```

**Example**

```
var student = new Student("SomeName",1,"SomeMajor");

Console.WriteLine(student);

MutateStudent(ref student);

Console.WriteLine(student);

var student2 = AbetterMutateStudent(student);

Console.WriteLine(student2);
```

**Output**

```
SomeName, 1, SomeMajor
ByrRefName, 2, ByrRefMajor
ByCopyName, 3, ByCopyMajor
```